# Code refactoring using lambda - Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I was just looking into the basics of functional programming. I want to convert the below code using lambda in Java. I am using java 8. any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
        String reinBranches = (String) application.getAttribute("xx_xx_xx");

    if(reinBranches != null && reinBranches.length() > 0)
    {
        String reinBranchArray[] = reinBranches.split(",");
        for(int i = 0; i < reinBranchArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(reinBranchArray[i].equals((String) session.getAttribute("xyz_xyz_xyz"))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: The first rule to use a lambda is: *is your target interface a functional interface*?

Comment: You mean you want to convert the implementation to one with a stream?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat : The point is i am just a newbie on functional programming. I am in a phase of trying to convert my code. I just wanted to know if i can convert this small piece into lamda or not.

Comment: @daniu yes exactly!

Comment: why negative vote ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I would get the attribute you want to match against and save it (before the lambda). Then `stream` the `String[]` from your `split` and return `true` if `anyMatch` your criteria. Finally, use a logical and to prevent NPE on the `return`. Like,

```
String reinBranches = (String) application.getAttribute("xx_xx_xx");
String xyz3 = (String) session.getAttribute("xyz_xyz_xyz");
return reinBranches != null && Arrays.stream(reinBranches.split(",")).anyMatch(xyz3::equals);
```

**or** as suggested in the comments using `Pattern.splitAsStream` which can short-circuit if a match is found without building the array from splitting

```
return reinBranches != null && Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(reinBranches).anyMatch(xyz3::equals);
```

Comment: `Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(reinBranches).anyMatch(s -> s.equals(session.getAttribute("xyz_xyz_xyz")));`

Comment: There’s never a need for a boolean literal in a compound expression. In this specific case, the simplified expression is `reinBranches != null && Arrays.stream(reinBranches.split(",")).anyMatch(attr::equals)`. Another alternative worth considering is to get rid of the `split` operation: `reinBranches != null && reinBranches.matches( "(.*,)?"+Pattern.quote(xyz3)+"(,.*)?");`

Comment: @Holger Very nice. I clearly need more coffee. Keurig on!

Comment: `Pattern.splitAsStream` has the advantage of not generating an array of all substrings in advance. Since `anyMatch` is short-circuiting, this can truly reduce the amount of work compared to `String.split`+`Arrays.stream`. On the other hand, `String.split` has an optimized code path for single character separators which likely wins for small to medium sized strings…

Answer (score 0):

Magic

```
BooleanSupplier r = () -> {
    String reinBranches = (String) application.getAttribute("xx_xx_xx");

    if(reinBranches != null && reinBranches.length() > 0)
    {
        String reinBranchArray[] = reinBranches.split(",");
        for(int i = 0; i < reinBranchArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(reinBranchArray[i].equals((String) session.getAttribute("xyz_xyz_xyz"))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Holger also, it's community wiki so you could've just edited it

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing same without any overhead of using streams:-

```
String reinBranches = (String) application.getAttribute("xx_xx_xx");
String xyz3 = (String) session.getAttribute("xyz_xyz_xyz");

return reinBranches != null && Pattern.compile(xyz3).matcher(reinBranches).find(0);
```